# SQL Server, Create List into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

In SQL Server, Want to create a list from a query into 1 column.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PatientMeds') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PatientMeds


Create Table #PatientMeds (name varchar(50), medication varchar(50))

Insert INTO #PatientMeds (name, medication)
values
('Patient 1', 'Med 1'),
('Patient 1', 'Med 2'),
('Patient 2', 'Med 1'),
('Patient 2', 'Med 2'),
('Patient 2', 'Med 3')
```

Table:

```
name    medication
Patient 1   Med 1
Patient 1   Med 2
Patient 2   Med 1
Patient 2   Med 2
Patient 2   Med 3
```

Desired Output:

```
name    medication
Patient 1   Med 1, Med 2
Patient 2   Med 1, Med 2, Med 3
```

Comment: There are no lists or arrays in SQL Server. You can get a comma-separated string at best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no arrays in T-SQL. Now that even SQL Server 2016 [is out of mainstream support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sql-server-2016), one can say that [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is available in all SQL Server versions still in mainstream support. Using it you can write just

```
SELECT 
    name,
    STRING_AGG(medication, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY medication) as medication
FROM ThatTable
GROUP BY name
```

Without `WITHIN GROUP` SQL Server is free to return the results in any order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
select name, string_agg(medication, ',') within group (order by medication) as medication
from #PatientMeds
group by name;
```

Note : If you are with some older versions then you may look `xml` approach.